# Group and count items using recursive sql

Tags: mysql, sql, recursion

I have the following data on my database. I have 3 tables Category, Item and ItemCategories.
The table Category have id, name, parent_crawler_id and crawler_id. Item have id and name. ItemCategories have id, item_id and category_id.

Below are the example data for Category:

```
id (pk)      name              parent_crawler_id            crawler_id
1            Fruit and Veg     null                         8899
2            Organic           8899                         88100
3            Green             88100                        88101
```

Below are the example data for Item:

```
id(pk)       name              
1            Grapes
2            Apples
```

Below are the example data for ItemCategories

```
id           item_id (fk)      category_id (fk)
1            1                 2
2            2                 3
3            1                 3
4            2                 2
```

I want to group the Category table and include the count of its descendants.
I want to get the following output:

```
name            count
Fruit and Veg   6
Organic         4
Green           2
```

Here is my query

```
WITH RECURSIVE category_tree AS (
  SELECT id, name, parent_crawler_id, crawler_id
  FROM "Category"
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT c.id, c.name, c.parent_crawler_id, c.crawler_id
  FROM "Category" c
  JOIN category_tree ct ON c.parent_crawler_id = ct.crawler_id
)
SELECT ct.name, SUM(subquery.count) AS total_count
FROM category_tree ct
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT ic.category_id, COUNT(DISTINCT ic.item_id) AS COUNT
  FROM "ItemCategories" ic
  GROUP BY ic.category_id
) subquery ON subquery.category_id = ct.id
GROUP BY ct.name
ORDER BY ct.name
```

How do I achieve this using using sql and recursive?

Comment: What have you written yourself so far?

Comment: @TanveerBadar 
I have updated my question with my initial query.
Thanks

Comment: Provide tables structures not as verbal description but in complete CREATE TABLE form.

Comment: Green is child of Organic, so why for Organic you want 2 (and not 2+2)? Only top rows of hierarchy should be summed?

Comment: Well... something like [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/q9TgcXem), it's unclear why you want 2 for Organic.

Comment: @PonderStibbons yes you are right it should be 4. I have updated the table.

Comment: @Akina I have added foreign key and primary key. Thanks

Comment: I mean the result should be 2 for Green, 4 for Organic (2 Organic and 2 Green) and **4 for Fruit nad Veg** (2 Organic, 2 Green). Anyway my dbfiddle should work.

Comment: @PonderStibbons yes you are right but the Fruit and Veg it should be 6 (4 + 2). Can we adjust the query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive CTE to build path and then use this path to sum values coming from descendant rows:

```
with recursive counted as (
  select c.id cid, max(parent_crawler_id) par, max(crawler_id) chd, count(ic.id) cnt
  from Category c
  left join ItemCategories ic on ic.category_id = c.id
  group by c.id),
rec(cid, par, chd, cnt, pth) as (
  select cid, par, chd, cnt, cast(chd as char(1000)) 
  from counted c where par is null
  union all
  select c.cid, c.par, c.chd, c.cnt, concat(rec.pth, '-', c.chd) 
  from counted c join rec on rec.chd = c.par)
select cid, pth, cnt, 
       (select sum(cnt) from rec r where pth like concat(rec.pth,'%')) summed
from rec
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/w3EFjpz8)

In my dbfiddle I added some more rows for testing purposes.

Comment: I have tried this, but the result is inconsistent. It does not total the correct descendants.